# setting rules/triggers on rally

Tags: rally

Does anyone know if it's possible to define rules or trigger on rally?

For example, field X is required only if field Y is defined and so on?

Also, is there a way to create a field that acts like a plan Estimate field? I want to define custom QA estimate field and want it be updated once the child QA estimate has been changed (that happens automatically in plan Estimate field but I looking to have this functionality in my custom field.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom rules and workflows aren't currently possible in Rally, although it's a popular feature request. I'd recommend signing into [Rally Ideas](http://ideas.rallydev.com), and adding your and your teammates' votes and comments to the following Idea:

[Add definable workflow enforcement into work fields to enforce agile process](http://ideas.rallydev.com/ideas/D966)

Which will enhance the visibility of this feature request with Rally's product owners and usability teams.